# How send arraylist from android to asp.net webservice

Tags: android, ksoap2

```
           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("birthday", dateString);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidhttpTranport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

i send a param is type String as `request.addProperty("birthday", dateString);`
How do  i send a `Arraylist<Object>` ?

Comment: What is `SoapObject`? Is this one of your classes or does it come from a library you are using.

Comment: See.. http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/android-calling-a-web-service-using-ksoap2-passing-values-to-a-web-service/

Answer (score 2):

It depends your web service, if you have an array of objects or primitives you can build a loop iterating through and adding into SoapObject. Check for [this one](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Adding_an_array_of_complex_objects_to_the_request)